# What are COM components in .NET?

Tags: asp.net

What are com components in dot net. I have read several articles and I am confused with what it exactly is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [Component Object Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model)

> Component Object Model (COM) is a binary-interface standard for
> software componentry introduced by Microsoft in 1993. It is used to
> enable interprocess communication and dynamic object creation in a
> large range of programming languages. COM is the basis for several
> other Microsoft technologies and frameworks, including OLE, OLE
> Automation, ActiveX, COM+, DCOM, the Windows shell, DirectX, and
> Windows Runtime.

Comment: @sly_Chandan: Read the Wikipedia article I linked.

Comment: It's COM.  It's Microsoft's Application Programming Interface designed to facilitate component-oriented programming.  I don't know how to explain it any simpler than that.  Study it, if you have an interest.  COM is notable in .NET because it's not a native API; you have to do something called Interop to use it in managed assemblies.

Comment: Here, try this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3129/A-Friendly-Approach-to-COM-Basics

Comment: So the com components can be written in any other language that supports pointer? for example java or any other language

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27892/discussion-between-sly-chandan-and-robert-harvey)

Comment: Thanks Robert. I have a fair idea of what com components are. If you have any other article that explains even further then pls share it.